# error: object MinMaxScaler is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml.feature

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to fix below error while importing from spark-scala shell

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler
error: object MinMaxScaler is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml.feature

Comment: Presumably you're missing the libraries that have that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving ClassNotFoundException exceptions / object x is not a member of package y in Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-classnotfoundexception-exceptions-object-x-is-not-a-member-of-packag)