# Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception, nosuchmethoderror

The common problems when building and deploying Spark applications are:

- `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.
- `object x is not a member of package y` compilation errors.
- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

How these can be resolved?

Comment: Typically these errors happen because your application is not bundled correctly. When I'm working on something in Maven or SBT is usually analyze the output of  `jar tf jar-file` which prints the classes in a jar.

Comment: Very well phrased question! Kudos! (Covers a variety of problems that have a common cause..)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When building and deploying Spark applications all dependencies require compatible versions.

- **Scala version**.  All packages have to use the same major (2.10, 2.11, 2.12) Scala version.

  Consider following (incorrect) `build.sbt`:

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "2.0.1"
  )
  ```

  We use `spark-streaming` for Scala 2.10 while remaining packages are for Scala 2.11. A **valid** file could be

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "2.0.1"
  )
  ```

  but it is better to specify version globally and use `%%` (which appends the scala version for you):

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.1"
  )
  ```

### Similarly in Maven:

```
    <project>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <name>Simple Project</name>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <properties>
        <spark.version>2.0.1</spark.version>
      </properties> 
      <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

- **Spark version** All packages have to use the same major Spark version (1.6, 2.0, 2.1, ...).

  Consider following (**incorrect**) build.sbt:

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.1",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "2.0.1"
  )
  ```

  We use `spark-core` 1.6 while remaining components are in Spark 2.0.  A **valid** file could be

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.0.1",
     "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "2.0.1"
  )
  ```

  but it is better to **use a variable** 
  (still incorrect):

  ```
  name := "Simple Project"

  version := "1.0"

  val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion,
     "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % sparkVersion,
     "org.apache.bahir" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % sparkVersion
  )
  ```

### Similarly in Maven:

```
    <project>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <name>Simple Project</name>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <properties>
        <spark.version>2.0.1</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
      </properties> 
      <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_${scala.version}</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

- Spark version used in Spark dependencies has to match Spark version of the Spark installation. For example **if you use 1.6.1 on the cluster you have to use 1.6.1 to build jars**. Minor versions mismatch are not always accepted.
- Scala version used to build jar has to match Scala version used to build deployed Spark. By default (downloadable binaries and default builds):

  - Spark 1.x -> Scala 2.10
  - Spark 2.x -> Scala 2.11
- Additional packages should be accessible on the worker nodes if included in the fat jar. There are number of options including:

  - `--jars` argument for `spark-submit` - to distribute local `jar` files.
  - `--packages` argument for `spark-submit` - to fetch dependencies from Maven repository.

  When submitting in the cluster node you should include application `jar` in `--jars`.

Answer (score 34):

Apache Spark's classpath is built dynamically (to accommodate per-application user code) which makes it vulnerable to such issues. [@user7337271](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7337271/user7337271)'s answer is correct, but there are some more concerns, depending on the **cluster manager** ("master") you're using.

First, a Spark application consists of these components (each one is a separate JVM, therefore potentially contains different classes in its classpath):

1. **Driver**: that's *your* application creating a `SparkSession` (or `SparkContext`) and connecting to a cluster manager to perform the actual work
2. **Cluster Manager**: serves as an "entry point" to the cluster, in charge of allocating *executors* for each application. There are several different types supported in Spark: standalone, YARN and Mesos, which we'll describe bellow.
3. **Executors**:  these are the processes on the cluster nodes, performing the actual work (running Spark *tasks*)

The relationsip between these is described in this diagram from Apache Spark's [cluster mode overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html):

[image: Cluster Mode Overview]

Now - **which classes should reside in each of these components?**

This can be answered by the following diagram:

[image: Class placement overview]

Let's parse that slowly:

1. **Spark Code** are Spark's libraries. They should exist in *ALL* three components as they include the glue that let's Spark perform the communication between them. By the way - Spark authors made a design decision to include code for ALL components in ALL components (e.g. to include code that should only run in Executor in driver too) to simplify this - so Spark's "fat jar" (in versions up to 1.6) or "archive" (in 2.0, details bellow) contain the necessary code for all components and should be available in all of them.
2. **Driver-Only Code** this is user code that does not include anything that should be used on Executors, i.e. code that isn't used in any transformations on the RDD / DataFrame / Dataset. This does not necessarily have to be separated from the distributed user code, but it can be.
3. **Distributed Code** this is user code that is compiled with driver code, but also has to be executed on the Executors - everything the actual transformations use must be included in this jar(s).

Now that we got that straight, **how** do we get the classes to load correctly in each component, and what rules should they follow?

1. **Spark Code**: as previous answers state, you must use the same **Scala** and **Spark** versions in all components.

   1.1 In **Standalone** mode, there's a "pre-existing" Spark installation to which applications (drivers) can connect. That means that **all drivers must use that same Spark version** running on the master and executors.

   1.2 In **YARN / Mesos**, each application can use a different Spark version, but all components of the same application must use the same one. That means that if you used version X to compile and package your driver application, you should provide the same version when starting the SparkSession (e.g. via `spark.yarn.archive` or `spark.yarn.jars` parameters when using YARN). The jars / archive you provide should include all Spark dependencies (**including transitive dependencies**), and it will be shipped by the cluster manager to each executor when the application starts.
2. **Driver Code**: that's entirely up to - driver code can be shipped as a bunch of jars or a "fat jar", as long as it includes all Spark dependencies + all user code
3. **Distributed Code**: in addition to being present on the Driver, this code must be shipped to executors (again, along with all of its transitive dependencies). This is done using the `spark.jars` parameter.

**To summarize**, here's a suggested approach to building and deploying a Spark Application (in this case - using YARN):

- Create a library with your distributed code, package it both as a "regular" jar (with a .pom file describing its dependencies) and as a "fat jar" (with all of its transitive dependencies included).
- Create a driver application, with compile-dependencies on your distributed code library and on Apache Spark (with a specific version)
- Package the driver application into a fat jar to be deployed to driver
- Pass the right version of your distributed code as the value of `spark.jars` parameter when starting the `SparkSession`
- Pass the location of an archive file (e.g. gzip) containing all the jars under `lib/` folder of the downloaded Spark binaries as the value of `spark.yarn.archive`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the very extensive answer already given by user7337271, if the problem results from missing external dependencies you can build a jar with your dependencies with e.g. [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

In that case, make sure to mark all the core spark dependencies as "provided" in your build system and, as already noted, make sure they correlate with your runtime spark version.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency classes of your application shall be specified in the **application-jar** option of your launching command.

More details can be found at the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/submitting-applications.html)

Taken from the documentation:

> application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and
>   all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your
>   cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is
>   present on all nodes

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem must solve a assembly plugin. 
You need build a fat jar. 
For example in sbt :

- add file `$PROJECT_ROOT/project/assembly.sbt` with code `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")`
- to build.sbt`added some libraries`libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.some.company" %% "some-lib" % "1.0.0")`
- in sbt console enter "assembly", and deploy assembly jar

If you need more information, go to https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Answer (score 0):

Add all the jar files from spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\jars in the project. The spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7 can be downloaded from  https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score -1):

I have the following build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "spark-samples",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("StreamingExample")        
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "spark-connector" % "2.2.0" 
)

// META-INF discarding
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
       case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
       case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
```

I've created a fat jar of my appliction using sbt assembly plugin, but when running using spark-submit it fails with the error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/Completable$OnSubscribe
    at com.couchbase.spark.connection.CouchbaseConnection.streamClient(CouchbaseConnection.scala:154)
```

I can see that the class exists in my fat jar:

```
jar tf target/scala-2.11/spark-samples-assembly-1.0.jar | grep 'Completable$OnSubscribe'
rx/Completable$OnSubscribe.class
```

not sure what am i missing here, any clues?

Comment: I had copied the dependency com.couchbasespark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar manually from SBT cache ( .ivy2 ) into my spark installation, after removing this the fat jar worked fine.