# Error in connecting oracle database to apache spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

Below is the code that I am using to connect to oracle local database from apache spark java program, but I am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method).
```

Here is my code.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
  SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
  Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
  options.put("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.85:1521/stage");
  options.put("dbtable", "AD_TABLES.brands");
  DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(options).load();
}
```

Below is the POM file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
  <version>11.2.0.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: can you put stack trace here. 
Seems some class possibly missing in class-path set by you while running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving ClassNotFoundException exceptions / object x is not a member of package y in Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-classnotfoundexception-exceptions-object-x-is-not-a-member-of-packag)

Answer (score 0):

You have Spark SQL version 1.6 and Spark Core 2.0

Change Spark SQL version also to 2.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Spark-CSV is also only for Spark 1.x, Spark 2 has this functionality built in the SQL project

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same version of spark libraries in your pom.xml. you are using `spark-core` and `spark-mllib` with version 2.0.1 while your `spark-sql` has 1.6.1 version. Change it to 2.0.1 like below.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

With Spark 2.0 you need not to create separate sqlContext as you can work with SparkSession like below.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("JDBCSample")
  .master("local[2]")
  .getOrCreate();
```

Now you can read data from database using SparkSession like below. For more details please check [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases).

```
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("user", "username");
connectionProperties.put("password", "password");
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF2 = spark.read().jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties);
```

Comment: I was 30 seconds faster ^^ My answer has hint with Spark CSV, yours has about SparkSession