# Error while running PageRank and BFS functions on Graphframes in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-1.6, graphframes

I'm new to Spark, and am learning it on the Cloudera Distr for Hadoop (CDH). I'm trying to execute the PageRank and BFS functions through Jupyter Notebook, which was initiated using the following command:

```
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

The below is the PageRank function command I tried to run, along with the error message:

```
ranks = tripGraph.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=5)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-34d549cc033e> in <module>()
----> 1 ranks = tripGraph.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=5)
      2 ranks.vertices.orderBy(ranks.vertices.pagerank.desc()).limit(20).show()

/tmp/spark-3bdc323d-a439-4f0a-ac1d-4e64ef4d1396/userFiles-0c248c5c-29fc-44c7-bfd9-3543500350dc/graphframes_graphframes-0.1.0-spark1.6.jar/graphframes/graphframe.pyc in pageRank(self, resetProbability, sourceId, maxIter, tol)

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o106.run.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.backport.PageRank$.log(PageRank.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.backport.PageRank$.logInfo(PageRank.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.backport.PageRank$.runWithOptions(PageRank.scala:148)
    at org.graphframes.lib.PageRank$.run(PageRank.scala:130)
    at org.graphframes.lib.PageRank.run(PageRank.scala:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm getting the same error messages for the BFS function I'm trying:

```
filteredPaths = tripGraph.bfs(
  fromExpr = "id = 'SEA'",
  toExpr = "id = 'SFO'",
  maxPathLength = 1)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-74394b11f50d> in <module>()
      4   fromExpr = "id = 'SEA'",
      5   toExpr = "id = 'SFO'",
----> 6   maxPathLength = 1)
      7 
      8 filteredPaths.show()

/tmp/spark-3bdc323d-a439-4f0a-ac1d-4e64ef4d1396/userFiles-0c248c5c-29fc-44c7-bfd9-3543500350dc/graphframes_graphframes-0.1.0-spark1.6.jar/graphframes/graphframe.pyc in bfs(self, fromExpr, toExpr, edgeFilter, maxPathLength)

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o147.run.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.graphframes.lib.BFS$.log(BFS.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:58)
    at org.graphframes.lib.BFS$.logInfo(BFS.scala:131)
    at org.graphframes.lib.BFS$.org$graphframes$lib$BFS$$run(BFS.scala:212)
    at org.graphframes.lib.BFS.run(BFS.scala:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you please let me know the issue?

Thanks, Sasi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incompatible Scala versions:

- `graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6` - Scala 2.10
- `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0` - Scala 2.11
- [Spark installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853641/error-while-running-pagerank-and-bfs-functions-on-graphframes-in-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment82703154_47853641) - Probably Scala 2.10.

You have to use the same Scala version for all components (`com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0` if Spark is compiled with Scala 2.10). Please consult [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383460/8371915) for details.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed acknowledgement...but this was helpful, and am slowly getting around the stuff! Many thanks.

Comment: Not a problem. Could you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and / or upvote the answer?

Comment: Done (new to StackOvreflow as well :))