# AbstractMethodError creating Kafka stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to open a Kafka (tried versions 0.11.0.2 and 1.0.1) stream using `createDirectStream` method and getting this AbstractMethodError error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaUtils.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.log(KafkaUtils.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logWarning(Logging.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.logWarning(KafkaUtils.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.fixKafkaParams(KafkaUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.<init>(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:124)
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
val preferredHosts = LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
    val kafkaParams = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[IntegerDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> groupId,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest"
    )

    val aCreatedStream = createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, preferredHosts,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
```

I have Kafka running on 9092 and I'm able to create producers and consumers and pass messages between them so not sure why it's not working from Scala code. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out I was using Spark 2.3 and I should've been using Spark 2.2. Apparently that method was made abstract in the later version so I was getting that error.

Comment: I had a similar issue incorrectly using spark-core 2.3.0 and spark-hive 2.1.0.  The versions must match.

Comment: Nice discussion of how to fix this here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/197922/spark-23-structured-streaming-integration-with-apa.html

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exception, in my case I created the application jar with dependency to `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` of version `2.1.0`, while trying to deploy to Spark 2.3.0 cluster.

Comment: I am having same issue while running spark submit in cluster .In my case dev environment was in    2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91  and QA env in 2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187 . How you solved the issue.Can you please explain . Which version of  spark-streaming-kafka  you have used

Comment: I think I changed the version of dependency to `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` to 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I recieved same error. I set my dependencies same version as my spark interpreter is

```
%spark2.dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("MavenCentral").url("https://mvnrepository.com/")

z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0")
z.load("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.0")
```