# How to process Debezium events from Kafka using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, debezium

I follow this instruction https://debezium.io/docs/tutorial-for-0-2/. My CDC running well for mysql event (Create, Update, Delete).

I try to get this kafka event from pyspark use python, my code still cannot get that event.

Below the code :

```
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/usr/local/spark"
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/home/azda/anaconda3/bin/python"
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"]="/home/azda/anaconda3/bin/python"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /usr/local/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10-2.2.0.jar pyspark-shell'

if __name__ == '__main__':

     conf = SparkConf().setAppName("DBWatcher").setMaster("local[3]")

     sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
     sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

     ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

     #Already try use :2181
     kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, '10.90.29.24:9092', 'spark-streaming', {'mysql-server-1.inventory.customers': 1})
     print('contexts =================== {} {}')
     lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
     lines.pprint()

     ssc.start()
     ssc.awaitTermination()
```

From this code, I got this following error :

> 2018-11-14 16:22:39 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 0) java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-11-14 16:22:39 WARN 
>   TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost,
>   executor driver): java.lang.AbstractMethodError   at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> 2018-11-14 16:22:39 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0
>   failed 1 times; aborting job 2018-11-14 16:22:39 INFO 
>   TaskSchedulerImpl:54 - Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  2018-11-14 16:22:39 INFO  TaskSchedulerImpl:54 -
>   Cancelling stage 0 2018-11-14 16:22:39 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 -
>   ResultStage 0 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in
>   0.438 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID
>   0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:600)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:590)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2185)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any suggest how to get stream data ?
Best Regards.

Comment: I would suggest `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10`

Comment: In general looks like you might be using a bad version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180931/abstractmethoderror-creating-kafka-stream

Comment: @cricket_007 I try to change the version <br/>os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /usr/local/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.0.jar pyspark-shell' <br/>still get same error. Also try to change <br/>os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.3.2 pyspark-shell'

Comment: dont use both `-0-8-assembly` and `kafka-0-10`... Also don't use `2.0.0.jar` if you aren't running Spark `2.0.0`. You should specify which versions of Spark you do have installed

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 , Thank you for fast response, actually my spark version is 2.3.2

I try to use these 3 way :
1. Use : os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2 pyspark-shell"
2. Use : os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2 pyspark-shell"
3. Use Both : os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2 pyspark-shell"

Unfortonutely still get same error.

Comment: Have you tried the structured streaming instead of getting a DStream? As per https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html And with using Spark2, you typically start with a SparkSession object and get the Context from it (minor detail here)