# Spark ClassNotFoundException with the simplest rdd.map

Tags: apache-spark, classnotfoundexception

**edit**
This question is not a duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark):

- the answers above are generalities about sharing code. I don't see how it applies to my issue
- Here I do not use spark-submit but simply call spark from an app running on my computer
- There is no dependency whatsoever. The only code to share is the simplistic function `i => i`
- if it is a problem of spark/java/scala version, I don't understand why it would produce a ClassNotFoundException for the function in question

---

I run this code

```
object Tmp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Spark Test")
      .setMaster("spark://[ip-of-spark-master]:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    sc.parallelize(0 until 10000).map(i => i).count()
  }
}
```

Which fails with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tmp$$anonfun$main$1` when I simply run it on my computer, without sending any jar. It works if I don't do the `map(i => i)` (i.e. it is the function `i => i` that is not found).

To be clear:

- I do not use spark-submit
- my computer is the driver and is not on the spark cluster
- I use the exact same spark version on my computer that is used in the cluster (2.0.2)

Now I thought that for simple function, spark would serialize it and there were no need to send the jar. I am pretty sure I have done it before.

Did I miss something ?

Looking at the stack trace, it fails on the driver, so on my side:

```
Driver stacktrace:
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)

...

[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tmp$$anonfun$1
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
...
```

Comment: How are you running the jar? How did you specify the classname ?

Comment: I run the code above on my computer (in intellij). So my computer is the driver and there is no jar, just class file compiled with intellij

Comment: Can you check that you use the same Spark version (seems you got that covered), compiled for and using the same Scala version, under the same JVM version ?

Comment: @GPI I also think it might be related to jvm version (spark could be using 7 while I am on 8). I will check. However, I don't know how to know which scala version was used for spark (I am currently using 2.11.12 because I think some project running on this cluster has this version)

Comment: if spark is not running in your machine then it should be local

Comment: @RameshMaharjan not necessarily. You can run the driver code on your machine if it can connect to the whole spark cluster. I use to do that for testing and debugging.