# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentials()

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop

I got this error when try to run "How to use the MongoDB Hadoop Connector with Spark." in this website: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage

```
Exception in thread "Thread-19" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentials()Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/Credentials;
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.addCredentials(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopRDD$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1187)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$newAPIHadoopRDD$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1178)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:692)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(SparkContext.scala:1178)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(JavaSparkContext.scala:506)
```

Any suggestion for me to resolve this problem. I'm new in spark and hadoop. I just want read my data from mongodb and save to hdfs.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: have you found solution for this question.