# How to make my java class writable by extending it with scala class?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, inheritance, sequencefile

I need to **saveAsSequenceFile** my Java class object(I cannot correct class itself for some reason), for that I have to make it Writable. I'm trying to extent my Java class with Scala class(can use only Scala) by implementing **write** and **readFields** method. I can save to file, but I cannot read:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $iwC$$iwC$ClassBWritable.<init>()
```

Seems like I have to create initial constructor for my ClassBWritable, but following doesn't work:

```
def this() = this(0, 0.0F)
```

**How to make initial constructor or solve my problem?**
My class(**need to fix its definition or add additional constructor**):

```
import ClassA
import java.io.{DataOutput, DataInput}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
class ClassBWritable(field1: Byte, field2: Float) extends ClassA(field1, field2)  with Writable{
    def this() = this(0.toByte, 0.0F)       
    override def write(out: DataOutput): Unit = {
        out.writeByte(getField1)
        out.writeFloat(getfield2)            
    }
    override def readFields(in: DataInput) : Unit = {
        setField1(in.readByte())
        setField2(in.readFloat())
    }
}
```

Here how I save to file:

```
myrdd.map(pair => (new LongWritable(pair.longNumber) -> new ClassBWritable(pair.my_byte_value, pair.my_float_value)))
     .saveAsSequenceFile(mypath)
```

How I read from file:

```
val df = sc.sequenceFile(mypath, classOf[LongWritable], classOf[ClassBWritable])
      .map(row => (p._1.get(), row._2.getField1(), row._2.getField2()) )
      .take(1)
```

My exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $iwC$$iwC$ClassBWritable.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: @GhostCat, i think this is the question more for spark's users=)

Comment: Scaladized spark users that is!

Comment: Have you checked [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383460/9613318)?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassBWritable(field1: Byte, field2: Long) ... {
    def this() = this(0, 0.0F, 0, 0.0F, 0.0F) ...
```

can't compile: it needs to be

```
    def this() = this(0.toByte, 0L)
```

instead. So you apparently have a different version of `ClassBWritable` in the classpath (judging by `$iwC$$iwC$ClassBWritable`, it was probably defined in the console instead of a file). Once you actually compile the class and make sure it's the one used in other files, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: I added conversion .toByte, it didn't help.
About version everything is OK, if you mean that first I wrote to file using one version ClassBWritable and then I'm trying to read using another way defined version of my class..