# What is a good alternative for Spark CatalystSqlParser?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have previously used CatalystSqlParser to parse input strings to DataType like this:

```
private def convertToDataType(inputType: String): DataType = CatalystSqlParser.parseDataType(inputType)
```

It was very convenient and easy to implement. However as I can see for now CatalystSqlParser is not available for use. The import `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser` is not working. 
Is there any alternative similar to CatalystSqlParser?

Comment: `CatalystSqlParser` works fine for me on 2.3 and master... Are you sure there is nothing wrong with dependencies?

Comment: @user8371915 you're probably right. As I've checked dependencies for the module, I've got `spark-sql_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.7.1.jar` and the following dependency  in pom.xml                                     
       `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @user8371915 what else should I check? For this import `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.CatalystSqlParser` I have the parser in red and "Cannot resolve symbol parser"

Comment: Is 1.6 an expected Spark version?

Comment: @user8371915 I have `spark-core_2.10` as a dependency. Haven't thought that 1.6 in spark-sql dependency refers to Spark version

Comment: `_2.10` is Scala version and `1.6.0` is Spark version. In general all have to match - [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383460/8371915)

Comment: @user8371915 What I did now is added this dependency and it fixed the problem with import.         `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>` Is it the right approach?

Comment: If this matches the rest of your dependencies then yes :) In short all components require at least the same major Spark and Scala versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can using CatalystSqlParser.parseDataType by calling DataType.fromDDL()