# SQL Server dependency not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I have packaged an application in a jar file using sbt for this purpose.
When I run the app from the IDE (IntelliJ) it works without issues.
However, when I try to run directly the jar, I have 2 different issues.

**When I run it from spark-submit, I get:**

```
[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ spark-submit --class com.my.app.main --master local[0] /home/cloudera/Projects/myapp/target/scala-2.11/myapp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource
```

**When I run it from java I get:**

```
[cloudera@quickstart scala-2.11]$ java -jar myapp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
    at com.my.app.main$.main(main.scala:13)
    at com.my.app.main.main(main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Remark that the JDBC for SQL Server is already placed in the lib folder, where it's suppossed to be automatically recognized by sbt when it generates the package.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: My question is not answered on that post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Sorry but the answer of that question is too wide to find the relationship with my question.

Answer (score 0):

taken from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546145/1498109

i would modify for your case:

```
   spark-submit --class com.my.app.main \
   --master local[0] /home/cloudera/Projects/myapp/target/scala-2.11/myapp.jar \
   --jars path_to/sqljdbc42.jar
```

this one worked for me, donwload the jdbc jar from official microsoft site.