# Connecting to sql database from Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to connect to a SQL database from spark and I have used the following commands:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext                                                                                                                                                                      
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

scala> val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)                                                                                                                                                    
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
sqlcontext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@2bf4fa1

scala> val dataframe_mysql = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver:192.168.103.64/DRE").option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").option("dbtable", "NCentralAlerts")
.option("user", "sqoop").option("password", "hadoop").load()
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
  ... 49 elided
```

I am seeing that Spark is looking for the SQL driver. Which directory do I place this SQL driver in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see from the logs that you are trying to run this using spark shell. Assuming you have the jar at hand. Start `spark-shell` with the following addition

```
spark-shell --jars /path/to/driver.jar
```

This way it will be added to you classpath and you will be able to use the driver.

Hope this helps