# Error loading data in Hbase using Hortonrworks shc core library

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, bigdata

We have been using EMR cluster for dev purpose and there I have used hortornworks provided shc core libraries to load HBase tables directly from spark data frames and it was all working fine.

Recently we have moved to use Cloudera 5.14 (which by default comes with spark 1.6 and scala 2.10, but we have upgraded that to spark 2.3 and scala 2.11).
The hbase load is failing with below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:146)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.createTable(HBaseRelation.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at com.sc.eni.config.HbaseConfiguration$.hbaseload(HbaseConfiguration.scala:47)
at com.sc.eni.core.Ingest$.loadLayer4(Ingest.scala:102)
at com.sc.eni.core.Ingest$$anonfun$runPipeline$1.apply(Ingest.scala:23)
at com.sc.eni.core.Ingest$$anonfun$runPipeline$1.apply(Ingest.scala:21)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
at com.sc.eni.core.Ingest$.runPipeline(Ingest.scala:17)
at com.sc.eni.main.tssStart$.main(tssStart.scala:38)
at com.sc.eni.main.tssStart.main(tssStart.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
```

We are using code/versions ->

cloudera verion : 1.2.0-cdh5.14.0

shc core : 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 (Repo : http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/)

spark: 2.3.0

scala: 2.11.8

```
table catalogue : def catalog = s"""{
|"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"test","tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"},
|"rowkey":"tradeid",
|"columns":{
|"tradeid":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"tradeid", "type":"string"},
|"eoddate":{"cf":"td", "col":"eoddate", "type":"string"},
|"buysell":{"cf":"td", "col":"buysell", "type":"string"},
|"trader":{"cf":"td", "col":"trader", "type":"string"},
|"exclegalentity":{"cf":"td", "col":"exclegalentity", "type":"string"},
|"intaccountid":{"cf":"td", "col":"intaccountid", "type":"string"},
|"intaccbook":{"cf":"td", "col":"intaccbook", "type":"string"}
|}
|}""".stripMargin

df.write
.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog,HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Beware of SHC! Look at the open issues on github before you deploy your application in production. SHC has major bugs and it seems that hortonworks folks does not maintain it anymore nor accepting critical pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like a version mismatch between HBase version deployed in the environment and spark shc-core being used.