# Apache Spark - Spark-Submit ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, spark-submit

I'm beginning in Apache Spark using Java API, Maven and IntelliJ Idea

I made a program but I get a "ClassNotFoundException".

```
Mac-mini:~ username$ spark-submit --class test.FirstRDD --master local IdeaProjects/exercices/out/artifacts/exercices_jar/exercices.jar
```

> 2018-07-06 10:09:56 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.FirstRDD
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>       2018-07-06 10:09:56 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
>       2018-07-06 10:09:56 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory
>   /private/var/folders/m_/y0g8dr8x4vx390cv6z23s47c0000gr/T/spark-e70c0995-5c0d-4bb5-9bc1-776b27786949

Here's my main class:

FirstRDD.java

```
package test;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;


import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class FirstRDD {

    public void run() throws URISyntaxException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Exercice 1").setMaster("local[*]");
        conf.setJars(new String[]{"/Users/username/IdeaProjects/exercices/out/artifacts/exercices_jar/exercices.jar"});
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        //sc.addJar("/Users/username/IdeaProjects/exercices/out/artifacts/exercices_jar/exercices.jar");

        Path url = Paths.get(FirstRDD.class.getResource("/ratings.txt").getPath());

        JavaRDD<Rating> lines = sc.textFile(url.toString())
                .map(line -> line.split("\\t"))
                .map(row -> new Rating(Long.parseLong(row[0]), Long.parseLong(row[1]), Integer.parseInt(row[2]), LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong(row[3])*1000),ZoneId.systemDefault()))
                );

        double count = lines
                .filter(rating -> rating.user==200)
                .count();

        double max = lines
                .filter(rating -> rating.user==200)
                .mapToDouble(rating -> rating.rating)
                .max(Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder());

        double min = lines
                .filter(rating -> rating.user==200)
                .mapToDouble(rating -> rating.rating)
                .min(Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder());

        double mean = lines
                .filter(rating -> rating.user==200)
                .mapToDouble(rating -> rating.rating)
                .mean();

        System.out.println("Count : "+count+" | Max : "+max+" | Min : "+min+" | Moyenne : "+mean);


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        //System.out.println(new test.FirstRDD().getClass().getCanonicalName());
        new FirstRDD().run();


    }
}
```

And my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>exercices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
            <spark.version>2.3.1</spark.version>
            <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Apache Spark temp - Release Candidate repo</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachespark-1080/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

What I've tried so far :

- Check in .jar if FirstRDD is present with "jar -tf exercices.jar"
- Check if FirstRDD is set as Main class in my artifact
- Check FirstRDD class name by a System.out.println
- Use groupId.artifactId.test.FirstRDD in class argument
- Use groupId.artifactId.main.java.test.FirstRDD in class argument
- Add .class to test.FirstRDD
- "run-example SparkPi 10" works

Comment: Spark 1.3.1 dependency looks suspicious.  Do you really use Spark 1.3.1 installation for submission?

Comment: Indeed, I'm running Spark 2.3.1 not 1.3.1. Thanks for noting it
I updated my pom.xml but the error is still here with the same error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: If you run 2.3.1 (please update the question to reflect) then it is probably Scala version mismatch - you seem to use 2.10, but available binaries use 2.11

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the changes, and I now use the syntax provided in the link you gave me.
Moreover, I looked into my installations and noticed that I installed Scala 2.12. I changed it for Scala 2.11.

Sadly, I still have the same error message