# How to apply Scala generic type in Spark with Kafka decoder?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

**[Update]**
Someone has a similar question: https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/issues/19
Seems there's no good solution to it.

**[Update]**
I don't think this is a duplicate question as [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark), as when I don't use Scala generic for the `Decoder`, everything is working well:

```
// This works.
class EnigmaDecoder(props: VerifiableProperties = null) extends Decoder[AdTracking] {
  override def fromBytes(bytes: Array[Byte]): AdTracking = {
    if (...)  null
    else AdTracking.parseFrom(...)
  }
}
```

**[Original Post]**
I have multiple message types (e.g. `AdTracking`). All of them have similar message manipulation interfaces, like a static member `AdTracking AdTracking::parseFrom(ByteString)`.

I don't want to duplicate the message parser one by one, so I wrap it with generic type in Scala.

```
trait BsParser[T] {
  def parseFrom(bs: ByteString): T  // T: AdTracking
}

object EnigmaDecoder {
  implicit object AdTrackingBsParser extends BsParser[AdTracking] {
    override def parseFrom(bs: ByteString): AdTracking = AdTracking.parseFrom(bs)
  }
}

class EnigmaDecoder[T >: Null : BsParser](props: VerifiableProperties = null) extends Decoder[T] {
  override def fromBytes(bytes: Array[Byte]): T = {
    if (...) null
    // call static method AdTracking::parseFrom(bs) to build an AdTracking object
    else implicitly[BsParser[T]].parseFrom(...)
  }
}
```

And this `EnigmaDecoder[AdTracking]` is used in Spark as:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, AdTracking, StringDecoder, EnigmaDecoder[AdTracking], (String, AdTracking)](
    ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets,  messageHandler)
```

Unfortunately, when I use this `EgnimaDecoder[AdTracking]` in Spark, I got such an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: EnigmaDecoder.<init>(kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.<init>(KafkaRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD.compute(KafkaRDD.scala:136)
```

I checked the compiled class, but don't know how to fix it.

```
Compiled from "EnigmaDecoder.scala"
public class EnigmaDecoder<T> implements kafka.serializer.Decoder<T> {
  private final BsParser<T> evidence$2;
  public static <T> kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties apply$default$1();
  public static <T> kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties $lessinit$greater$default$1();
  public static <T> EnigmaDecoder<T> apply(kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties, BsParser<T>);
  public T fromBytes(byte[]);
  public EnigmaDecoder(kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties, BsParser<T>);
}
```

Could anyone help me on this?
Thanks!