# resolving error with LabeledPoint.parse

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new in spark and I am trying this example:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Vector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object App {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
if (args.length != 5) {
  System.err.println(
    "Usage: StreamingKMeansExample " +
      "<trainingDir> <testDir> <batchDuration> <numClusters> <numDimensions>")
  System.exit(1)
}

// $example on$
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingKMeansExample")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(args(2).toLong))

val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream(args(0)).map(Vectors.parse)
val testData = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)).map(LabeledPoint.parse)

val model = new StreamingKMeans()
  .setK(args(3).toInt)
  .setDecayFactor(1.0)
  .setRandomCenters(args(4).toInt, 0.0)

model.trainOn(trainingData)
model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
// $example off$
}
}
```

but it cannot resolve LabeledPoint.parse it only has apply and unapply methods available not parse.

It's probably the version I am using. So this is my sbt

```
name := "myApp"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1"
)
```

**EDIT** so I made a custom made labelPoint class since nothing else worker that did solved the compile problem. But, I tried to run it and the predicted values are always zero. 
the input txt for train is

```
[36.72, 67.44]
[92.20, 11.81]
[90.85, 48.07]
 .....
```

and the test txt is

```
(2, [9.26,68.19])
(1, [3.27,9.14])
(9, [66.66,13.85])
 ....
```

So why the result values are 2,0 1,0 9,0 ? Is there a problem with labeledPoint?

Comment: The spark version you're using (`2.3.1`) has `LabeledPoint.parse` and it has been there since `1.1.0`, so not sure that's it. Where do you see this issue - when compiling/running locally or when running on a remote Spark master?

Comment: I get the error when compiling. Also the spark release I've installed is 2.2.0 if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: in the import it says multiple implementations and has mllib 2.10.0.9 incubating how can I remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: @TzachZohar Isn't that just a simple version mismatch (2.2 and 2.3.1)?

Comment: I'm not so sure, because (a) all versions mentioned here have a `parse` method with the same signature (as far as I could see), and (b) this is a local compilation issue (per OP), which means it's not involving more than one JVM, which means SBT should have taken care of any version mismatch / duplication and just grab the latest version. But I could be wrong, and I don't have an alternative explanation.

Comment: as @tzachZohar says both versions have parse method. so that didn't resolve the problem..

Comment: I edited the post