# Maven dependency hell for spark mlib ALS algorithm

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, dependencies

I have this small piece of java code to get apache spark recommendations:

public class Main {
    public static class Rating implements Serializable {
        private int userId;
        private int movieId;
        private float rating;
        private long timestamp;

```
    public Rating() {}

    public Rating(int userId, int movieId, float rating, long timestamp) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public static Rating parseRating(String str) {
        String[] fields = str.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Each line must contain 4 fields");
        }
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
        int movieId = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
        float rating = Float.parseFloat(fields[2]);
        long timestamp = Long.parseLong(fields[3]);
        return new Rating(userId, movieId, rating, timestamp);
    }
}

static String parse(String str) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9.]*,[0-9.]*]");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
        String substring = str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        String itstr = substring.split(",")[0].substring(1);
        sb.append(itstr + " ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}

static TreeMap<Long, String> res = new TreeMap<>();

public static void add(long k, String v) {
    res.put(k, v);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SomeAppName")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();
    JavaRDD<Rating> ratingsRDD = spark
            .read().textFile(args[0]).javaRDD()
            .map(Rating::parseRating);
    Dataset<Row> ratings = spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD, Rating.class);
    ALS als = new ALS()
            .setMaxIter(1)
            .setRegParam(0.01)
            .setUserCol("userId")
            .setItemCol("movieId")
            .setRatingCol("rating");
    ALSModel model = als.fit(ratings);
    model.setColdStartStrategy("drop");
    Dataset<Row> rowDataset = model.recommendForAllUsers(50);
    rowDataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
        String str = row.toString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(str.substring(1).split(",")[0]);
        add(l, parse(str));
    });
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
    for (long l = 0; l < res.lastKey(); l++) {
        if (!res.containsKey(l)) {
            bw.write("\n");
            continue;
        }
        String str = res.get(l);
        bw.write(str);
    }
    bw.close();
}
```

}

I am trying different dependencies in my pom.xml to get it running, but all variants fail. This one:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

fails with **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: text.DefaultSource**, to fix it I add

org.apache.spark
            spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10
            2.0.2

now it crashes with **ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class**, to fix it I add another ones:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

now it fails with **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce** to fix it I tried dozen of other combinations, all of them failed, the last one is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

which again gives me **ClassNotFoundException: text.DefaultSource**, how can I fix it? Was there any logic behind implementing runtime linking in spark?

UPD: also tried

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(this still gives me **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: text.DefaultSource**))

I also tried dependencies published in this question, but they also fail: [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Source code is available here, so you can try various maven settings yourself: https://github.com/stiv-yakovenko/sparkrec

Comment: The first file - `com.sparkjava` has nothing to do with Apache Spark (though core Spark should be a transitive dependency from mllib) and misses `spark-sql` dependency. The second file - you use inconsistent Scala versions.

Comment: The third one uses consistent version, but still has a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it work:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You have to use these exact versions otherwise it will crash in multiple various ways.

Comment: Use Maven Shade Plugin, you'll not have such issues in future, the shade plugin actually give a different package name if there are multiple versions,