# Spark job works when running locally but not working when on standalone mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple Spark code that works fine when running locally however when I Try to run it using Spark Standalone Cluster with Docker it strangely fails.

I can confirm that the integration with the master and the worker is working.

In the code below I show where the error raises.

```
JavaRDD<Row> rddwithoutMap = dataFrame.javaRDD();
JavaRDD<Row> rddwithMap = dataFrame.javaRDD()
            .map((Function<Row, Row>) row -> row);

long count = rddwithoutMap.count(); //here is fine
long countBeforeMap = rddwithMap.count(); // here I get the error
```

After the Map, I can't call any Spark's action.

the error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apssouza.lambda.MyApp$1`

Obs: I am using Lambda in the Map, to make the code more readable but I am also not able to use lambda when using the standalone version.
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.fun$1 of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1`

Docker image: `bde2020/spark-master:2.3.2-hadoop2.7`

Local Spark version: 2.4.0

Spark dependency version: spark-core_2.112.3.2

```
public class MyApp {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
//        String sparkMasterUrl = "local[*]";
//        String csvFile = "/Users/apssouza/Projetos/java/lambda-arch/data/spark/input/localhost.csv";

    String sparkMasterUrl = "spark://spark-master:7077";
    String csvFile = "hdfs://namenode:8020/user/lambda/localhost.csv";
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Lambda-demo")
            .setMaster(sparkMasterUrl);
         // .setJars(/path/to/my/jar); I even tried to set the jar
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
    Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(csvFile);

    JavaRDD<Row> rddwithoutMap = dataFrame.javaRDD();
    JavaRDD<Row> rddwithMap = dataFrame.javaRDD()
            .map((Function<Row, Row>) row -> row);

     long count = rddwithoutMap.count();
     long countBeforeMap = rddwithMap.count();

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.apssouza.lambda</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-arch</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>lambda-arch</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

Obs: If uncomment the first two lines everything works perfectly.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark

Comment: Please include the build definition.

Comment: U mean the docker-compose?

Comment: `pom.xml` would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was not packaging my program before running it and I was getting an outdated version of my app in the Spark cluster. This is weird because I am running it through my IDE(IntelliJ) and it should be packaging the jar before running it. Anyway, `mvn package` before hit the run button solved the issue.