# Kafka Structured Streaming KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am working on a streaming project where I have a kafka stream of ping statistics like so :

```
64 bytes from vas.fractalanalytics.com (192.168.30.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.913 ms
64 bytes from vas.fractalanalytics.com (192.168.30.26): icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.936 ms
64 bytes from vas.fractalanalytics.com (192.168.30.26): icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=0.980 ms
64 bytes from vas.fractalanalytics.com (192.168.30.26): icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=0.889 ms
```

I am trying to read this as a structured stream in `pyspark`. I start pyspark with the following command :

```
 pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0
```

Pyspark version is 2.4, python version is 2.7 (tried with 3.6 as well)

And I get an error as soon as I send this piece of code (followed from [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)):

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "172.18.2.21:2181").option("subscribe", "ping-stats").load()
```

I run into the following error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 23 more
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I managed to solve this by ensuring that the spark-sql-kafka package's version matches the spark version.

In my case, I am now using `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.1` for my spark version **2.4.1**, thereafter the `.format("kafka")` part of the code can be resolved.

Also, v2.12 of the package (i.e., `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.1`) does not seem stable at the time of writing, and using it will also cause the above error.

*EDIT: v2.12 `spark-sql-kafka` packages seem to only work with Spark built with Scala v2.12. Hence, for Spark v2.X versions (pre-built with Scala v2.11 by default), there's a need to instead use Spark binaries built with Scala v2.12 (e.g. `spark-2.4.1-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12.tgz`) if you really want to use `spark-sql-kafka` v2.12 package. For Spark v3.X, they are pre-built with Scala v2.12 by default, hence you'll only see/use v2.12 of the package.

Comment: Using Spark 2.4.4: I've also had crashes with ```org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4``` so reverted to ```org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4``` and everything works fine now.

Comment: For spark 3.0.0, use --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0

Comment: changing to spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 helped

Comment: spark 2.4.8 - this works org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.8

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved when used  the Spark version 2.3.2 with Scala version 2.11.11 and dependency org.apache.spark:sl-kafka-0-10_2.10:2.0.2

```
#spark-shell  -i Process.scala --master local[2]  --packages org.apache.spark:sl-kafka-0-10_2.10:2.0.2 ...
```