# Kafka "partition.assignment.strategy" in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to read the data to convert it to Dataframe and the current versions of my software are the following:

1. spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7
2. kafka_2.12-2.7.0

Kafka is working and I have the following data stored which I am trying to read:

```
~/development/kafka_home/kafka_2.13-2.6.0$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testtopic --from-beginning
{"transaction_id": "1", "transaction_card_type": "Visa", "transaction_amount": 181.76, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 15:44:44"}
{"transaction_id": "2", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 228.62, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 15:44:45"}
{"transaction_id": "3", "transaction_card_type": "Visa", "transaction_amount": 483.48, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 15:44:46"}
{"transaction_id": "4", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 477.87, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 15:44:47"}
{"transaction_id": "5", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 304.52, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 15:44:48"}
{"transaction_id": "1", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 346.99, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 16:38:44"}
{"transaction_id": "2", "transaction_card_type": "Maestro", "transaction_amount": 384.33, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 16:38:45"}
{"transaction_id": "3", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 394.95, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 16:38:46"}
{"transaction_id": "4", "transaction_card_type": "Visa", "transaction_amount": 22.75, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 16:38:47"}
{"transaction_id": "5", "transaction_card_type": "MasterCard", "transaction_amount": 492.01, "transaction_datetime": "2021-01-25 16:38:48"}
```

I am executing the following code in PySpark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "testtopic"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = 'localhost:9092'

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.7.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testtopic").load()
ds = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
query = ds \
  .writeStream \
  .queryName("tableName") \
  .option("partition.assignment.strategy", "range")
  .format("console") \
  .start()
```

and the error I am getting is the following:

> 21/01/25 18:53:41 WARN kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader: Error in attempt 1
> getting Kafka offsets: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException:
> Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which
> has no default value.

I have done some research and they have said that the .jar file called "kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar" seems to be the problem, however I have trained both 2.6.0 and 1.1.0 versions with same results.

**

### EDIT:

**

I have added the following in "spark-defaults"

```
spark.jars /home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.7.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.7.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.7.jar
spark.executor.extraLibrary /home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.7.jar
```

and creating my Session the following way:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PySpark Structured Streaming with Kafka Demo") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I am still recieving the following error:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
> org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be
> instantiated

for this line of code:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testtopic").load()
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html), you only need to include the following dependency:

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11
version = 2.4.7 <-- replace this by your appropriate Spark version
```

Spark warns against using the `kafka-clients*.jar` directly since it already includes those jars, and adding multiple jars for the same library can make debugging harder.

> **Do not** manually add dependencies on org.apache.kafka artifacts (e.g. kafka-clients). The spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 artifact has the appropriate transitive dependencies already, and different versions may be incompatible in hard to diagnose ways.

Comment: I have downloaded the .jar file you mentioned for my specific version. Now I get the following error on the line:

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "testtopic").load()

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated

Comment: Just to be sure you have removed all jars you have added in your classpath related to kafka including multiple versions mentioned in the question? This error is usually thrown because you are using an older version of the library.

Comment: I would also recommend you to provide these jars via arguments instead of code.

Comment: A relevant SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285151/kafka-structured-streaming-kafkasourceprovider-could-not-be-instantiated).

Comment: I have added a comment on the topics to have mentioned on the First post so it's more readable. I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Can you try passing the jar using `--jars` argument? Also, please verify from your command output that pyspark is loading your jar.

Comment: It is adding the package as it shows in the console "org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227815/discussion-between-jose-gutierrez-and-amit-singh).