# SparkStreaming 2.3.1 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark 2.3.1 and programming language as Java 8. Trying to connect to Twitter and get live feed of tweets.  Below is command for spark-submission, which I am using :

```
spark-submit  --class GetTwitterData --jars /root/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.3.1.jar,/root/twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar,/root/twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar sparkLearning-1.0.jar
```

Following exception is coming:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Looks like your missing a jar in your executor’s classpath.

Comment: @jgp A `NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates having the wrong **version** of a dependency on the classpath, not that a dependency is missing.