# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.withHttpClient

Tags: apache-spark, solr, solrj

I am following [this](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/lucidworks/spark/example/query/WordCount.scala) example to get data from Solr to my Scala Spark program. Below is my code:

```
val solrURL = "someurl"
val collectionName = "somecollection"

val solrRDD = new SelectSolrRDD(solrURL,collectionName,sc)

val solrQuery=new SolrQuery("somequery")
solrQuery.setTimeAllowed(0)

val solrDataRDD=solrRDD.query(solrQuery)
```

When I run this code on my local Spark cluster, I get the following exception at `new selectSolrRDD` line:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.withHttpClient(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;)Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/SolrClientBuilder;`

I looked at some other answers on StackOverflow but nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My cluster had jars of spark-solr already present which were conflicting with the jars I was using. After removing those jars, my code worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your packaging and deployment (your pom.xml assuming you are using maven). The issue is that the Solr client libraries are not being loaded when you run your Spark app. You need to package your app and any dependencies into an "uber jar" for deployment to a cluster.

Take a look at how [spark-solr](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/blob/master/pom.xml#L244) has it setup. They use the maven-shade-plugin to generate the uber jar.

Comment: I am using Scala and sbt and am building the jar using sbt assembly plugin which creates a fat jar. Could there be any other reason why solr libraries are not getting loaded?