# Databricks connect to CosmosDB (MongoAPI) via mongo_spark_connector

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

Trying to connect Databricks with CosmosDB (mongo api)

I have installed the mongo_spark_connector_2_12_2_4_1.jar
and run the below code.

```
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
> 
> my_spark = SparkSession \
>     .builder \
>     .appName("myApp") \
>     .getOrCreate()
> 
> df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \  
> .option("uri", CONNECTION_STRING) \   .load()
```

> CONNECTION_STRING that looks like that:
>   "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@testgp.documents.azure.com:10255/DATABASE_NAME.COLLECTION_NAME?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb"

Unfortunately I got into a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson

Hope to be able to connect successful and query using Pyspark.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Most likely Scala version mismatch. Unless you've built Spark yourself, the only released Spark version so far using Scala 2.12 is 2.4.2. Pre-built binaries of 2.4.1 use 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

You may receive this error message, due to mismatch of the dependencies in the packaging of jar version.

**Note:** Use the Azure Cosmos DB Spark Connector page is currently not up-to-date.

Instead of downloading the six separate jars into six different libraries, you can download the uber jar from maven at https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11/1.4.0/jar) and install this one jar/library.

For more details, refer "[Connecting Azure Databricks to Azure CosmosDB](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector.html)" and Using "[Accelerate big data analytics by using the Apache Spark to Azure Cosmos DB connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector)".

Hope this helps.