# Spark - Reading from SQL Server using com.microsoft.azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, apache-spark, azure-sql-database

I am trying to read from a table using com.microsoft.azure. Below is the code snippet

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.query._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date

 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("DbApp").getOrCreate()
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
    val config = Config(Map(
      "url"          -> "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433",
      "databaseName" -> "Student",
      "dbTable"      -> "dbo.MemberDetail",
      "authentication" -> "SqlPassword",
    "user"         -> "test",
    "password"     -> "****"
    ))
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.sqlDB(config)
    println("Total rows: " + df.count)
```

However I am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.SqlDBConfigBuilder.<init>(SqlDBConfigBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config$.apply(Config.scala:254)
    at com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config$.apply(Config.scala:235)
    at DbApp$.main(DbApp.scala:55)
    at DbApp.main(DbApp.scala)
```

MSSQL JDBC Version: mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8
azure-sqldb-spark version: 1.0.2

Could anyone kindly guide me what am I doing wrong.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: I am using Spark 2.12, could you help me with which version is compatible with azure-sqldb-spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to version (versions are mentioned in the question itself) conflict between com.microsoft.azure.sqldb and com.microsoft.jdbc driver, after downloading com.microsoft.azure.sqldb with all its dependencies from below link it worked.

Note: com.microsoft.azure.sqldb works on Java 8, I downgraded my java runtime version.

Click [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/releases/tag/1.0.2) to com.microsoft.azure.sqldb with all dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't seem to be set in your config nor specified anywhere else. `Class.forName` just validates presence of the JDBC driver. The driver is also for `microsoft.sqlserver`, which is different library.

Consider using this:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
import java.util.Properties
val jdbcHostname = "localhost"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "Student"
val jdbcTable = "dbo.MemberDetail"

val MyDBUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

val MyDBProperties = new Properties()
MyDBProperties.put("user", "test")
MyDBProperties.put("password", "****")
MyDBProperties.setProperty("Driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
val df = spark.read.jdbc(MyDBUrl, jdbcTable, MyDBProperties)
```

This approach was most stable in my environment (using Databricks and Azure SQL DB).

Related knowledgebase article available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases).

Comment: Hi Dan, I want to try Azure sqldb, so that I could use the bulk data load. your approach would help me to use com.microsoft.sqlserver but I still can't use azure sqldb.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using azure-sqldb-spark to connect to SQL server.

All connection properties in [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties) are supported in this connector. Add connection properties as fields in the com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config object.

You don't need to create the jdbc driver `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` again.

Your cold should be like this:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"            -> "locaohost",
  "databaseName"   -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"        -> "dbo.Clients",
  "user"           -> "username",
  "password"       -> "*********",
  "connectTimeout" -> "5", //seconds
  "queryTimeout"   -> "5"  //seconds
))

val collection = sqlContext.read.sqlDB(config)
collection.show()
```

Please ref:

1. [Connect Spark to SQL DB using the connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#connect-spark-to-sql-db-using-the-connector)
2. [azure-sqldb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Leon, I tried this but I am still getting the same error.